# Javascript server request handling

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small web application that will display the response from a server request like this: http://yourserver/download/request?host=2. The application needs to account for the fact that the response can contain over 10,000 fields.
It would take considerably long time to process all 10,000 fields and display them. In order to address this performance issue, I'm thinking I can break up the response into pages for example, each page has say 100 fields and then maybe some pagination from there. I can then show the first page to the users while more pages are being processed asynchronously. My questions are which framework or library should I use and how should I approach building such application? Many thanks.

the response of host=2 looks like:

```
{"configuration": [
  {
    "name": "host1",
    "hostname": "ntp-lab.com",
    "port": 1231,
    "username": "halo"
  },
  {
    "name": "host2",
    "hostname": "xml-lab.com",
    "port": 3345,
    "username": "admin"
  },
 ]
}
```

Comment: Change your Server query.

Answer (score 0):

For this to achieve, you can either choose between:

1. ProcessArray()
2. HTML5 Web Workers

`ProcessArray()` function accepts three arguments like below:

`function ProcessArray(data, handler, callback) {}`

For HTML5 Web Workers you may want to read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).